# Spivak Ch. 3 Question 4

Tags: algebra-precalculus

From Spivak *Calculus* 4th Edition, Chapter 3, Question 4:

Let $S(x) = x^2$, let $P(x) = 2^x$ and let $s(x) = \sin x$. Find each of the following. In each case your answer should be a *number*.

(i)   $(S \circ P)(y)$

(ii)  $(S \circ s)(y)$

(iii) $(S \circ P \circ s)(t) + (s \circ P)(t)$

(iv)  $s(t^3)$

The part I am struggling with is "your answer should be a number." How can the answer be a number if we are composing functions that are not inverses of each other?

Comment: $S\circ P (y)=(2^y)^2$ and so on. I suppose that qualifies as a number because it is a number when $y$ is a number (?)

Comment: I would interpret it as 'evaluates to a real number'.

Comment: I think @Maximilian Janisch is correct given that the answers in the answers to selected problems section of the book are i)$2^{2y}$ and iii)$2^{2sin(t)}+sin(2^t)$. It didn't give answers to ii and iv as it was only a select few questions.

Answer (score 0):

In the four parts, we are going to use that if $f$ and $g$ are any two functions, we define a new function $f\circ g$ by
$$(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x)).$$

(i) We have that
$$(S\circ P)(y)=S(P(y))=S(2^y)=(2^y)^2=\boxed{2^{2y}}$$
(ii) We have that
$$(S\circ s)(y)=S(s(y))=S(\sin y)=(\sin y)^2=\boxed{\sin^2 y}$$
(iii) We have that
\begin{align*}
        (S\circ P\circ s)(t)+(s\circ P)(t) &= (S\circ P)(s(t))+s(P(t)) =\\
        &= S[P(s(t)]+s(P(t)) =\\
        &= S[P(\sin t)]+s(2^t) =\\
        &= S(2^{\sin t})+\sin (2^t) =\\
        &= (2^{\sin t})^2+\sin (2^t) =\\
        &= \boxed{2^{2\sin t}+\sin (2^t)}
    \end{align*}
(iv) We have that
$$s(t^3)=\boxed{\sin (t^3)}$$

Let us now make clear the meaning that the answer has to be a number: in the different sections, we have that $y,t\in \mathbb{R}$ are any real number, therefore, the result as it only depends on $y$ or $t$, it is also a real number.